# Can a char * or char ** masquerade as a FILE *?

Tags: c, file, file-io, io

In C, I often want to handle data read from a file and data read from an array of strings the same way.  Usually reading from a file is for production and from strings is for testing.  I wind up writing a lot of code like this:

```
void handle_line(char *line, Things *things) {
    ...
}

Things *read_from_chars(char *lines[]) {
    Things *things = Things_new();

    for (int i = 0; lines[i] != NULL; i++) {
        handle_line(lines[i], things);
    }

    return things;
}

Things *read_from_input(FILE *input) {
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t linelen = 0;

    Things *things = Things_new();

    while (getline(&line, &linelen, input) > 0) {
        handle_line(line, things);
    }

    return things;
}
```

This is a duplication of effort.

Is there a way I can make an array of strings masquerade as a `FILE *` pointer?  Or vice-versa?  Or is there a better pattern for dealing with this problem?

For bonus points: the solution should make `char *` or `char **` usable with the standard file functions like `fgets` and `getline`.

Comment: There's nothing built in. Your method looks good to me. If you were using C++ you could use classes or overloaded functions, but C doesn't have anything like that.

Comment: You could overload by creating functions with variadic arguments. *shrug*.

Comment: can you just write a function that reads a file into a list of char*? like read_from_chars(get_lines(file));

Comment: There's not really any duplication of effort in your current solution. The common code is in a common function `handle_line`,  and the two functions `read_from_chars` and `read_from_input` do two different tasks (in fact, the two tasks you need to support).  This would be a normal solution to the problem.  A more complicated approach would be for the processing function to invoke a callback to read a line when it needed a line

Comment: @user3125280 That's not a good solution as reading the whole file into memory is inefficient.

Comment: @M.M That I have to write `read_from_chars` and `read_from_input` is the duplication of effort. They both conceptually do the same things: initialize the output variable, call a callback for each line.

Comment: @Schwern huh? the solution that you accepted stores the entire data in memory anyway, as does the code you posted for read_from_chars. and as you wrote the read-from-file is usually for testing where efficiency is not important. now you are relying on platform specific functions and github libraries for no real reason?

Comment: @user3125280 It only stores the data in memory if the source is already in memory (ie. `char *`). If the source is a file, it will read that file line by line. Though I see I got the testing/production cases backwards in the question, my apologies. The Github library is fine as it's simple enough to copy into my projects, and it can be made to only load if a native `fmemopen` is not available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a nonstandard function `fmemopen` that lets you open a char[] for reading or writing.  It's available in most versions of GNU libc, I think, and most versions of Linux.

(This lets you read from or write to a single string, not the array of strings you asked about.)

Comment: Unfortunately, the input argument to the OP's first function is `char *lines[]`.

Comment: `fmemopen` is backed by `fopencookie` which allows for custom (eg, you provide them) read/write/seek/close functions. I don't see much reason you can't write them to read `char *lines[]` instead of `char data[]`.

Comment: @RSahu The signatures are not set in stone.

Comment: `fmemopen` does not exist on BSD operating systems (I'm using OS X), [but I found an implementation](https://github.com/lemurs/fmemopen). Thanks! This answer gives me full flexibility to pass strings into anything that accepts a `FILE *`.

Comment: @Schwern: Glad you found that package, and thanks for mentioning it, because it might come in handy for me on my Mac, too!

Answer (score 6):

You could use a discriminated union that contains a `FILE*` and a pointer to the array, then write a `get_next` function that does the right thing with it.

```
typedef struct {
    enum { is_file, is_array } type;
    union {
        FILE *file;
        struct {
            int index;
            int size;
            char **lines;
        } array;
    } data;
} file_or_array;

char *get_next(file_or_array foa) {
    if (foa.type == is_file) {
        char *line = NULL;
        size_t linelen = 0;
        getline(&line, &linelen, foa.data.file);
        return line;
    } else {
        if (foa.data.array.index < foa.data.array.size) {
            return strdup(foa.data.array.lines[foa.data.array.index++]);
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

The call to `strdup()` is necessary to make this work consistently. Since `getline()` returns a newly-allocated string, which the caller needs to free, it also does the same thing when returning a string from the array. Then the caller can safely free it in both cases.

Comment: Why not fix the leak by having `get_next()` return `strdup(foa.array.lines[...])` in the array case? That would make the design consistent - the caller always needs to free.

Comment: An interesting idea, but it only works for functions which understand the union.

Comment: so that's how you do polymorphism in C. Interesting.

Comment: @Schwern Right, this is an abstraction layer.

Comment: `file_or_array` should be a struct with `array` and `file` as union members.

Comment: @a3f Thanks for the correction, I've updated the code

Answer (score 2):

One of the most powerful ways to handle this is via streams.  I use them to hide file/string/serial ports etc

I have rolled my own stream library which I mainly use on embedded systems

the general idea is :-

```
typedef struct stream_s stream_t;

struct stream_s
{
    BOOL (*write_n)(stream_t* stream,  char* s, WORD n);
    BOOL (*write_byte)(stream_t* stream,  BYTE b);
    BOOL (*can_write)(stream_t* stream);
    BOOL (*can_read)(stream_t* stream);
    BYTE (*read_byte)(stream_t* stream);
    void* context;
};
```

then you make a whole bunch of functions

```
BOOL stream_create(stream_t* stream);
BOOL stream_write_n(stream_t* stream, char* s, WORD n);
BOOL stream_can_read(stream_t* stream);
BYTE stream_read_byte(stream_t* stream);
```

etc

that use those base function call backs.

the context in the stream struct you use to point to a struct for serial, string, file, or whatever you want.  Then you have things like `file_create_stream(stream_t* stream, char* filename)` which will populate the callbacks on `stream` with the file related functions.  Then for strings you have something similar but handles strings

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I'd rather use the standard stream processing functions. That way I can pass test data to anything that takes a file pointer.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a better pattern for dealing with this problem?

My proposed solution is to do function overloading.

Provide all possible parameters:

```
Things* readThings(FILE *f, char *l[])
{
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t linelen = 0;
    Things *things = Things_new();

    if (f)
    {
        while(getline(&line, &linelen, input) > 0)
            handle_line(line, things);
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; lines[i] != NULL; i++)
            handle_line(lines[i], things);
    }

    return things;
}

Things* readThingsChar(char *l[]){ return readThings(0, l); }

Things* readThingsFile(FILE *f){ return readThings(f, 0); }
```

How to use

```
FILE *f;
char *l[100];

..

Things *a = readThings(f,0); // or readThingsFile(f)
Things *b = readThings(0,l); // or readThingsChar(l)
```

---

You could embed it in the data:

```
Things* readThings(char *l[])
{
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t linelen = 0;
    Things *things = Things_new();
    FILE *f = NULL;

    if (l[0][0]==UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER)
    {
        f = fopen(l[0]+1);

        while(getline(&line, &linelen, input) > 0)
            handle_line(line, things);

        fclose(f);
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; lines[i] != NULL; i++)
            handle_line(lines[i], things);
    }

    return things;
}
```

How to use

```
char *f[1] = { "_file.txt" };
char *l[100] = { "first line", .. "last line" };

f[0][0] = UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER;

Things *a = readThings(f);
Things *b = readThings(l);
```

Comment: C doesn't have overloading like that.

Comment: That would work, but it only works for one particular function written that way.

Comment: @MillieSmith I kinda forgot, fixed now.

Comment: This is very similar to what the OP is doing already.  He is asking for something more generic, so he does not have to duplicate or special case all of his code.

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one way to skin this particular cat, but in general the solution to this is hiding the implementation of the public interface behind an indirection which allows you to inject separate 'implementations'.

(This incarnation of your problem is also closely related to somewhat different problem of ensuring ABI compatibility between versions of code.)

To solve this in C you can do it similar to the pimpl with-inheritance in C++ (protected instead of private d-pointer, with overridden protected constructors):

You create an opaque 'reader'/'stream' object (pointer to forward declared struct w/ typedef in C) and suitably named constructor functions to instantiate the opaque object which inject the desired implementation.

Let's sketch out example header files to give you an idea of how the functions fit together. Let's start with the guts, the definition of the d-pointer/p-impl objects (N.B.: I'm omitting some boilerplate like header guards):

**reader-private.h**:

```
/* probably should be in its proper C file, but here for clarification */
struct FileReaderPrivateData {
   FILE * fp;
};

/* probably should be in its proper C file, but here for clarification */
struct StringReaderPrivateData {
   size_t nlines;
   size_t cursor;
   char ** lines;
};

/* in C we don't have inheritance, but we can 'fix' it using callbacks */
struct ReaderPrivate {
   int (* close)(void* pData); /* impl callback */
   ssize_t (* readLine)(void* pData, char** into); /* impl callback */
   /* impl-specific data object, callbacks can type cast safely */
   void * data;
};

/* works like a plain p-impl/d-pointer, delegates to the callbacks */
struct Reader {
    struct ReaderPrivate * dPtr;
}
```

**reader.h**:

```
typedef struct Reader* Reader;
/* N.B.: buf would be a pointer to set to a newly allocated line buffer. */
ssize_t readLine(Reader r, char ** buf); 
int close(Reader r);
```

**file-reader.h**

```
#include "reader.h"
Reader createFileReader(FILE * fp);
Reader createFileReader(const char* path);
```

**string-reader.h**

```
#include "reader.h"
Reader createStringReader(const char**, size_t nlines);
```

That's a general pattern for doing pimpl/d-pointer with inheritance in C, so you can abstract the implementation guts behind a public interface which is accessed through opaque pointers. This mechanism is generally useful to guarantee API and ABI compatibility between various implementations of the public interface and to implement a simple inheritance pattern.

Comment: Thanks. The drawback is, like most of the other answers, this leaves me with my own private IO system. I can only use it with functions which are aware of this system.

Comment: @Schwern correct. You are right: it's mostly interesting as a simple to follow demonstration of the general technique which you may find useful for making other parts of your code more extensible and/or testable, as well as forwards and/or backwards compatible (notably ABI compatible).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation using `fcookieopen` [IIRC, BSD has something similar]:

```
// control for string list
struct cookie {
    char **cook_list;                       // list of strings
    int cook_maxcount;                      // maximum number of strings

    int cook_curidx;                        // current index into cook_list
    int cook_curoff;                        // current offset within item
};

int cookie_close(void *vp);
ssize_t cookie_read(void *vp,char *buf,size_t size);

cookie_io_functions_t cook_funcs = {
    .read = cookie_open;
    .close = cookie_close;
};

// cookie_open -- open stream
FILE *
cookie_open(char **strlist,int count,const char *mode)
// strlist -- list of strings
// count -- number of elements in strlist
// mode -- file open mode
{
    cookie *cook;
    FILE *stream;

    cook = calloc(1,sizeof(cookie));
    cook->cook_list = strlist;
    cook->cook_maxcount = count;

    stream = fopencookie(cook,mode,&cook_funcs);

    return stream;
}

// cookie_close -- close stream
int
cookie_close(void *vp)
{

    free(vp);

    return 0;
}

// cookie_read -- read stream
ssize_t
cookie_read(void *vp,char *buf,size_t size)
{
    cookie *cook = vp;
    char *base;
    ssize_t totcnt;

    totcnt = 0;

    while (size > 0) {
        // bug out if all strings exhausted
        if (cook->cook_curidx >= cook->cook_maxcount)
            break;

        base = cook->cook_list[cook->cook_curidx];
        base += cook->cook_curoff;

        // if at end of current string, start on the next one
        if (*base == 0) {
            cook->cook_curidx += 1;
            cook->cook_curoff = 0;
            continue;
        }

        // store character and bump buffer and count
        *buf++ = *base;
        size -= 1;
        totcnt += 1;

        cook->cook_curoff += 1;
    }

    return totcnt;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. [Someone has already done that and put it on Github](https://github.com/lemurs/fmemopen).

Comment: Since you have a _list_ of strings, I'm not sure `fmemopen` will work for that. That's why I coded `fcookieopen`. I've had to do this for my own stuff and `fmemopen` or `open_memstream` always seemed to come up short, depending--YMMV

Comment: Well, if you can switch your code from `char **list` to `char *bigbuf = "line1\nline2\n...\n"`, `fmemopen` should be fine. Also, what I've found, is that sometimes it's just easier to dump the string list to a temp file [invisibly], open that with `fopen(tmp,"r"); unlink(tmp)` and treat normally. Again, whatever suits you best.

Answer (score 1):

If you need this functionality just for debugging, write a `fopen_strings(char *list[])` function to:

- create a temporary file
- open that with `fopen` with mode `"r+"`
- write all your strings into it
- delete the file (the FILE* can still operate on it, until it is closed either explicitly or implicitly at program end.  You might need to skip this step on some operating systems that prevent deletion of open files.
- `rewind` the stream
- return the stream and let your program use it as it would a regular file.