# C - Error with function parameters when it is being called

Tags: c

When I am trying to call a function, the parameters that I have tried so far have just resulted in the terminal saying that 'too few arguments to function' and what I can tell that what it wants written there is the parameters from when it was declared. I have read a few different documents about this and what the calling parameters are and the different between calling by value or by reference but I am still not able to figure out the problem.
Below is the main section of code that has the call functions in it along with some variables.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{//main()

char *listwords;

processfile(listwords); //<- this is the line that is causing the problem

WordList mylist;

initialiselist(&mylist);

addword(&mylist, createfillednode(listwords));

printlist(&mylist);
}//main()
```

Below here is the processfile() function:

```
//process the file
void processfile(WordList *wordList, int argc, char *argv[])
{//process file
    //file pointer
    FILE *f;
    //open the file
    f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    //check it opened correctly
    if(f == NULL)
    {//if statement
        printf("cannot read file\n");
    }//if statement

    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);

    //declare variables
    char *listwords;
    long size = ftell(f);
    char *token;

    //seek beginning of file
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    //set the size of array to the file size
    listwords = (char*)malloc(size+1);
    listwords[size] = '\0';
    //reads the data from the file
    fread(listwords, size, 1, f);

    int i;
    for(i=0; (token = strsep(&listwords, " ")); i++)
    {//for loop replace certain characters with spaces
        if (token != ".")
        {
            //pointer from the token to the dictionary
            wordList->token;
        }else if (wordList->token != "!")
        {

            wordList->token;
        }else if (token != "?")
        {

        wordList->token;
        }else if (token != "\"")
        {

            wordList->token;
        }else if (token != ","){

            wordList->token;
        }else
        {

            wordList->token;
        }
        //increment token to the next word
        token++;
    }//for loop replace certain characters with spaces
    fclose(f);
    return;
}//process file
```

Thanks.

Comment: `processfile` takes 3 parameters. You are passing 1. What could be wrong?

Comment: ***too.few.arguments.to.function***. How is that not clear?

Comment: `processfile(listwords);` --> `processfile(listwords, argc, argv);`, provided, `WordList` is a typedef to `char`.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `processfile` to take three arguments.

```
void processfile(WordList *wordList, int argc, char *argv[])
```

But you're only giving it one.

```
processfile(listwords);
```

And it's also the wrong type.  It should be a `WordList`, but instead it's a string (`char *`).

```
char *listwords;
```

In C, you have to give a function exactly the right number of arguments and of the right type ([C can do some type casting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#C-like_languages), but it's strictly defined and usually about numbers).

With one exception. [Variadic arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h#Declaring_variadic_functions) let you pass an undefined number of arguments.  This is how functions like `printf` work.  In general you should avoid variadic functions as much as possible, they add complexity and defeat type checking.

---

In your case, `processfile` only needs two arguments: a list of words, and a filename to open.  `argc` is never used, and knowing that the filename is coming from `argv[1]` puts an unnecessary restriction on the function.

```
void processfile(WordList *wordList, char *filename)
```

Then it can be called with...

```
WordList *wordList = ...generate the wordlist somehow...

processfile(wordList, argv[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `processfile()` function takes three arguments according to your definition:

`void processfile(WordList *wordList, int argc, char *argv[])`

However, in your `main()` function you're only passing a single argument:

`processfile(listwords)`

To make this work like you'd want it to, you'd have to pass all three arguments; your `listwords`, as well as the counter and vector for arguments:

`processfile(listwords, argc, argv)`

However, in general, this is usually not a great idea programatically speaking as far as I know.  A function should typically take some sort of specialized input and return a relevant value, and not the input from the command line - that should be parsed far ahead of the function actually being called.  Check out [getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html#Getopt) or [argparse](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html#Argp) to process arguments correctly, determine what parameters you *really* want to pass to `processfile()` and pass only the arguments that would be relevant to the file in which you're attempting to process.  From reading your code, probably just the file descriptor, which should be opened in `main()` after some argument-parsing error correction:

```
void processfile(WordList *wordList, FILE *f)
{
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);

    //declare variables
    char *listwords;
    long size = ftell(f);
    char *token;

    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    listwords = (char*)malloc(size+1);
    listwords[size] = '\0';
    fread(listwords, size, 1, f);
    - - - - - - - - - 8< - - - - - - - - -
```

This way, you can open your file elsewhere, and re-use `processfile()` on any open file called in any context, making it a more robust function.

Comment: Definitely better to take a `FILE *` open file pointer than a `char *filename`. Let the caller figure out where that `FILE *` comes from. [It could even be a string masquerading as a file!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34888149/14660)